# Pandas: how to apply weight column to create a new dataframe with weighted data

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset from US Census Bureau with weighted data:

```
    Weight  Income ......
2     136    72000
5      18    18000
10     21    65000
11     12    57000
23     43    25700
```

The first person represents 136 people, the second 18 and so on. There are a lot of other columns and I need to do several charts and calculations. I will be too much work to apply the weight every time I need to do a chart, pivot table, etc.

Ideally, I would like to use this:

```
df2 = df.iloc [np.repeat (df.index.values, df.PERWT )]
```

To create an unweighted or flat dataframe.

This produces a new large (1.4GB) dataframe:

```
     Weight Wage
0    136    72000
0    136    72000
0    136    72000
0    136    72000
0    136    72000
.....
```

The thing is that using all the columns of the dataset, my computer runs out of memory.

Any idea on how to use the weights to create a new weighted dataframe?

I've tied this:

```
df2 = df.sample(frac=1, weights=df['Weight'])
```

But it seems to produce the same data. Changing frac to 0.5 could be a solution, but I'll lose 50% of the information.

Thanks!

Comment: You say, "[It] will be too much work to apply the weight every time I need to do a chart, pivot table, etc." but from your memory constraint it sounds like this is not true, and in fact it will be much less work if you just write a set of helper functions for yourself where the helper function applies a weighted version of whatever operation you want to do for charts or pivot tables.

Comment: Is it really too much work to do `df[['Income']].apply(np.average, weights=df.Weight)`, for instance?

Comment: @ALollz it's not so easy. For instance, I've tried to calculate the median income and found median doesn't support weighting. Not to mention that I have many more complex charts, tables, and calculations to do. `df[['Income']].apply(np.median, weights=df.Weight)`

Comment: What do you think about this: `df2 = df.sample(frac=20, weights=df['Weight'], replace=True)`, and use the new dataframe. Reference: `frac : Fraction of axis items to return.`